# PVC threaded fitting broken off. How can I remove?

Tags: pipe, pvc

showing broken fittting that is stuck... the white fitting is the new replacement.. you see threaded end is same as piece stuck in the pool filter [image]

Answer (score 9):

There are also internal pipe wrenches available just for this situation:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Lotsa options, including the hacksaw method mentioned by bombcar, none of them foolproof or easy:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Carefully use a saw like this

[image]

it'll take a hacksaw blade.

Comment: If you cut most of the way through the pvc, but not into the threads in the filter housing, you should be able to use a small screwdriver or knife to pry the broken fitting out.

Answer (score 0):

I used a Dremel and tried to grind/file/route away some of the pipe (essentially to make a channel along the length of the tube, to try to weaken the circle).

You'll have to be careful b/c you don't want to grind down the threads on the pipe that is the receiver of the connection.
You'll also have to be careful b/c the Dremel is an electric tool and you're around water.

After this, I used a small screwdriver and a hammer to gently wedge it between to two pipes.  Eventually it separated the two pipes enough where I was able to use some needle nose pliers to grab it and start to rip off parts of the pipe.

[image: temoved pipe piece]